# How to find the number of ways to arrange $6$ men in a row such that $3$ particular men are consecutive

Tags: permutations

Find the number of ways to arrange $6$ men in a row such that $3$ particular men are consecutive.

Now first I have to select those $3$ men which can be done in $C(6,3)$ ways. How do I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to choose the three particular men. They're chosen for you, which is what they phrasing means.

Comment: @Arthur i think this is what i missed. if particular word was not written in question then how would i have proceeded?

Comment: Well, then the whole "consecutive" thing would be a bit strange, saying that the are three men that should be consecutive, but it doesn't matter who they are. Might as well just ask about the number of ways to arrange then without restrictions, which gives $6!=720$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, we can view the three particular men who sit in a block of consecutive seats as one object, which gives us four objects to arrange, the block of three men who sit in consecutive seats and the other three men.  How many ways can the four objects be arranged in a row?

> $4!$

How many ways can the three particular men be arranged within the block?

> $3!$

How many seating arrangements does this yield?

> $4!3!$

Comment: if particular word was not written in question then how would i have proceeded?

Comment: In this context, the word particular is needed to distinguish this problem from that of simply arranging six men in a row.